# PHP initialising date

Tags: php, datetime, date

I have the day,month and year of a date.I have found that php has date class regarding with dates.How to initialise a date class object with dd-mm-and yyyy..

Comment: Did you find that the date class has also [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)?

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look at the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php)...

Comment: :(  ..............................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`DateTime`](http://php.net/DateTime) class accepts the format `DD-MM-YYYY` in its constructor:

```
$date_str = '7-25-2012';
$datetime = new DateTime($date_str);
```

Comment: so can i add 1 day to the date like ...$datetime+1...is there such operator overloading? ..or whether i need to reinitialise

Comment: also is it possible to compare dates using operators like >,<etc

Answer (score 1):

Php.net is your friend! 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

So it would like that -

```
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
```